# Do I need to get a new AFSP approval if I change to a new part 61 instructor?

Tags: flight-training, general-aviation, usa, tsa

I have an [AFSP (TSA)](https://www.flightschoolcandidates.gov) approval to train with a part 61 provider. I want to transfer from them to an individual part 61 CFI. Do I need to go through the AFSP approval process again?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Do you already have TSA approval to train at a part 141 school, but you want to switch to a part 61 instructor? If so, is your question whether that requires another TSA approval?

Comment: i have approval to train at part 61, and want to switch to part 61 instructor for a Private Pilot License.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**, you will need to apply for AFSP approval for your new training provider. The [Application Guide](https://www.flightschoolcandidates.gov/afsp2/common_servlet/help.html?clean=1&nav=guide) for the AFSP says in step 7:

> It is possible for a Candidate to have several active training requests at a given time. These requests may be for the same or different flight training providers. Each training request form will be processed separately; AFSP approval is valid only for the Provider listed in the application.

So if you needed AFSP approval for your original training provider, you will need a new approval to switch to a different provider.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you do.  I've had two Germans and an Indian receive training from me while here on visas.  I was freelance, and they all had to go through ASFP.

There must be a new training request submitted each time a student in this situation changes training providers, and yes, I had to register with flightschoolcandidates.gov as a flight training provider and was involved with the students' application processes.

Comment: did you have to register with AFSP or TSA as a flight trainer so people could select your name as instructor. Because i see only flight schools in the list

Comment: The question was rewritten and now this does not answer it.

Comment: @Arun yes, you will need to communicate with your desired instructor on this issue.  He/she will need to register.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, every flight school change is a new request according to the [AOPA FAQ for aliens](https://www.aopa.org/advocacy/pilots/alien-flight-training-program/faq). You might not need to give fingerprints but you will have to pay the 130$ registration fee again to go to a different flight school.

Answer (score 2):

You can't transfer an approval so yes, you need to get a new one. From [AFSP's Application Guide](https://www.flightschoolcandidates.gov/home#Manage):

> - TSA cannot transfer your training event request from one flight training provider to another flight training provider. TSA approval is
>     valid only for the flight training provider listed on the training
>     event request.
> - You may desire to build more flight hours than the flight training provider can accommodate. You may train simultaneously with more than
>     one flight training provider; however, you must submit a flight
>     training event request for each provider.