# Can I transfer TSA approval between flight schools?

Tags: flight-training, tsa

I have finally been approved by the TSA for my current school and it has not been one month.

If I decide to change the flight school, can my TSA can be transferred fast without any fee?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! If your school is part 61, we already have [a question about that](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/27770/62).